# I have a hidden parameter but I want to give it a value

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting, reporting-services

I have a paramter in SSRS I am setting to hidden.  I want to send it to a stor proc but I want to use it only if it is default, if not, then I dont want to use it.  So, I have a parameter "DateBeginMod", which I will use for default if the user wants modified type.  If user does not want modified type, then I will use the other date "DateBegin" which is already there.  Im only now doing this because they want subscriptions.  Im just creating the "DateBeginMod" parameter, but I will only use it if is a subscription.  In the stor proc I will check for 'modification' or 'not modification' and use the DateBeginMod if it is.  So I just want DateBeginMod ALWAYS to equal "DateBegin", unless in the case it is a subscription then it wil be different defaults. Makes sense I hope

Comment: Basically my question is -- am I never allowed to have "available values" if I have a hidden paramater

Comment: Why would you want to have available values on a parameter that is hidden so that the available values can never be selected? Couldn't you solve your problem by simply having a default date for DateBegin and just use that? DateBeginMod seems superfluous to your needs.

Comment: You can set default values for hidden parameters. This is nice if you need to validate parameters being passed over programmatically. However, if you are using the default viewer these will not be able to be set by the user. In this case, a default value would be required if non-null able.

Comment: The DateBeginMod is differnt than the DateBegin obviously or else I would use it.  I got it working I had to create a nother parameter as a subscription flag check.  Thanks for all who tried to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the user should pick one of the ways (from the actual report), You can use the user's choice (the selected value) to re-render your report with the relevant parameter (`DateBeginMod` or `DateBegin`) according to the user's choice.

In my personal opinion - assuming that your parameters are actual dates, I would use single paramter with `IIF` expression to check the user's choice and to set the date accordingly.

Comment: Its for subscriptions and the the IIF statement woudl work from user enetering the data but Im only using defaults here